# How can I create a session token in Sabre REST API?

Tags: sabre

I need to create a session token on Sabre API and I do not find any documentation on that and the only documentation available is create a sessionless token.

The same time, the session less token cannot be used in booking.

Here is the link to the documentation and it is telling only the session token is available for SOAP communications.

```
https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/how_to_get_a_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Sabre does not offer booking functionality via Rest - only Soap.

You also wont find the calls to make a booking via Rest

Comment: But I see creating PNR in their API and here is the link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record

Comment: Also there are ticketing capabilities in their JSON service and here is the link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/fulfill/enhanced_air_ticket

Comment: You are right - they were released mid Decemeber. But the doc also states that sessionless token is sufficient. I would however recommend using the soap api enhanced airbook + pessangerdetails request as they are better documented and in my experience better performing

Comment: Certification did not take place for us as we are already using Sabre red workspace (not sure if it does for anyone).